# What is the statistical steady state of this poisson process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> Suppose there is an island with some amount of people. The arrival of new people on the island follows a Poisson process with rate parameter $\lambda$. Suppose further that the time until a person departs the island is exponential with rate constant $\mu$. Assume all arrival and departure times are independent. An *event* is the arrival of a new person or departure of an existing person.
>
> a) Suppose there are $n$ people on the island at time $t$. What is the probability distribution of time until the next event?
>
> b) What is the probability that the next event is a departure?
>
> c) Assume a statistical steady state exists. What is the expected number of people  in this steady state?

**Attempt**

Assuming my attempt on a) and b) is correct, I would like to understand better how to approach c).

For a), let $T$ be the time until the next event. Then
$$ P(T<s) = 1 - e^{-s(\lambda + \mu n)}$$
so the density is given by
$$ (\lambda + \mu n)e^{-s(\lambda + \mu n)}.$$
Hence $T$ is exponential with rate constant $(\lambda + \mu n)$.

For b), I discretized time and examined
$$ P( T = k \, \Delta s \cap N_{t+k\,\Delta s} = N_t ) $$
where $N_{t+k\,\Delta s} = N_t$ is the number of new people in time $k \,\Delta s$. This leads to
$$ P( \text{Next event is a departure} ) = 
\frac{\lambda + \mu n }{ 2\lambda + \mu n}.$$
Which seems to make sense, since for large $n$, the probability that the next event is a departure is large.

Now, for part c), I'm not sure how to marry the two concepts above to arrive at a formula for the statistical steady state. I expect I need to arrive a formula for a time $t$ and take $t \to \infty$. If my solutions for a) and b) are right, is there a logical way to use them to produce the answer for c)?

Comment: You have two Poisson processes with rates $\lambda$ and $n\mu$ added together. The chances that the next event is departure is $\frac {n\mu}{n\mu +\lambda}$. For steady state, write down equation that signify zero change of probability density at every point.

Comment: Steady state is $Pois(\frac \lambda\mu)$, so average number of people is $\frac\lambda\mu$

Comment: Distribution-free argument: Rate of change of $n$ people is $\lambda-n\mu$.. In steady state, expected rate of change must be zero - hence $n=\lambda/\mu$.

Comment: @A.S. I'd like to understand both your approaches. How do you arrive at a rate of change of $n$ people of $\lambda - n \mu$? On your first comment, what is the equation that signifies zero change of probability density? If this is the density of the number of people on the island, how do you find that density from the given processes?

Comment: When population is $n$, people arrive at rate $\lambda$ and leave at rate $n\mu$, so total rate of change is $\lambda-n\mu$. In steady stated, expected rate of change is zero, so $\lambda-E(n)\mu=0$. To find steady state distribution, write down balance equation (which is detailed balance in this case): $\pi_iP_{i,i+1}=\pi_{i+1}P_{i+1,i}$ to immediately get Poisson relation for $\frac {\pi_{n+1}}{\pi_n}$.

Comment: In the above example, $P$'s should be $Q$'s - that is rates of change, not probabilities of steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant0\}$ be the number of people on the island at time $t$, and $\{X_m:m=1,2,\ldots\}$ be time of the $m^{\mathrm{th}}$ event. 
Since the arrival and departure processes are Markovian, $N(t)$ is a continuous-time Markov chain with embedded Markov chain $X_m$, having transition probabilities
$$
\mathbb P(X_{m+1}=j\mid X_m=i) = \begin{cases}
\frac\lambda{\lambda+i\mu},& j=i+1\\
\frac{i\mu}{\lambda+i\mu},& j=i-1.
\end{cases}
$$
So given $N(t)=n$, it follows that
$$\mathbb P(T>s) = e^{-(\lambda+n\mu)s},\ s>0. $$
Let $q_{ij}$ be the transition rate from state $i$ to state $j$. If a stationary distribution $\pi$ exists, then $\pi$ must satisfy the global balance equations $$\sum_{j\in S\setminus\{i\}}\pi_i q_{ij} = \sum_{j\in S\setminus\{i\}}\pi_j q_{ji} $$
for each $j\in S$ (here the state space is $S=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$). Since
$$
q_{ij} = \begin{cases}
\lambda,& i=j+1\\
(i+1)\mu,& i=j-1,
\end{cases}
$$
the balance equations are given by
$$\lambda\pi_n = (n+1)\mu \pi_{n+1},\ n\geqslant 0, $$
which yields the recurrence
$$\pi_n =\left(\frac\lambda\mu\right)^n\left(\frac1{n!}\right)\pi_0,\ 
n\geqslant0. $$
Set $\rho = \frac\lambda\mu$. From $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n=1$ it follows that 
$$\pi_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\rho^n}{n!}=1, $$
and hence 
$$\pi_n = \frac{e^{-\rho}\rho^n}{n!}. $$
By inspection, $\pi$ is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\rho$, and so $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb E[N(t)] = \rho. $$

Alternatively, we can compute the stationary distribution directly from the transition rates. For each $i,j\geqslant 0$, define the generator (or transition rate matrix) by
$$
G_{ij} = \begin{cases}
q_{ij},& i\ne j\\
-\sum_{j\ne i}q_{ij},& i=j
\end{cases}
$$ 
Let $P(t)$ be the matrix with entries $\mathbb P(N(t)=j\mid N(0)=0)$.Then $P$ satisfies the differential equations
\begin{align}
[P'(t)]_{ij}&=[P(t)G]_{ij}, P(0) = \mathsf I,\quad t>0\\
[P'(t)]_{ij}&=[GP(t)]_{ij}, P(0) = \mathsf I,\quad t>0
\end{align}
i.e. the Kolmogorov forward and backward equations. The solution is given by
$$P(t) = e^{tG} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tG)^n}{n!}, $$
and so for any $j\in S$, $$\lim_{t\to\infty}P(t)_{ij} = \pi_j $$ is the stationary distribution of $N(t)$.

Now, to actually compute $\pi$, we use the following result:
$$\pi = \pi P \iff \pi G=0. $$
(This is a good exercise to prove.). Here the generator matrix is given by
$$G_{ij} = \begin{cases}
\lambda,& i=j-1
-(\lambda+i\mu),& i=j 
(i+1)\mu,& i=j+1,\end{cases}
$$
so we have
\begin{align}
-\lambda\pi_0 + \mu\pi_1=0&\implies \pi_1 = \rho\pi_0,\\
\lambda\pi_0 - (\lambda+\mu)\pi_1 + 2\mu\pi_2&\implies \pi_2 = \frac{\rho^2}{2!}\pi_0,
\end{align}
and for $n\geqslant 2$, induction yields
$$\pi_n = \frac{\rho^n}{n!}\pi_0. $$
As before,
$$\pi_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\rho^n}{n!}=1\implies \pi_0 = e^{-\rho}  $$
and hence
$$\pi_n = \frac{e^{-\rho}\rho^n}{n!}. $$

Comment: how did you arrive at the mass functions as functions of time "i", $\lambda / (\lambda + i \mu)$ and $i \mu / (\lambda + i \mu)$? I don't have this in my answers.

Comment: Also, I'm a little unsure of how you derived the balance equation?

Comment: Those are the transition probabilities in the embedded Markov chain of the CTMC. I'll add some detail in the post about the balance equations.

Comment: Thanks, that would be helpful so that I can review your answer again in more detail.